# Records.slice doesn't slice sorted store

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, slice, jsonstore

I have a jsonstore.

```
var speedDialStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                pageSize: 4,
                proxy   : {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'speedDialListByHospitalID.html',
                    actionMethods: {
                        create: 'POST', read: 'POST', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'
                    },
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'results',
                        totalProperty: 'total',
                    }
                },
                fields      : [{name:"id"},{name:"code"},{name:"name"},{name:"description"},{name:"hospitalID"},{name: "buildingID"},{name: "floorID"},{name:"alarmID"},{name:"notificationFrequency"},{name:"maxCount"},{name:"start"}],
                listeners: {
                  load : function (store, records, success, operation, options) {
                    if(records != null){
                        store.loadData(records.slice(records[0].get('start'),records[0].get('start')+4));
                    }
                  } 
                }

            });
```

And a grid that uses this store.

My problem is when grid is sorted i need to sort all the store and just show first 4 element for the first page and second 4 element for the second page so on..

```
listeners:{
                        'sortchange': function(ct, column, direction, eOpts ){
                                Ext.getCmp('speedDialPaging').moveFirst();
                                speedDialStore.sort(column.dataIndex, direction);
                        }
                    },
```

after the slice method works, grid still shows the unsorted 4 elements. But if i add alert message or breakpoint at slice method i see that the store is sorted properly. Therefore (i think) i need to modify slice method or find any other way to solve this problem.. Server is sending all the data. We have to solve this problem here not server side.

Comment: try `grid.getView().refresh()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn't work. The problem isn't about grid refresh. After sorting store it refreshes automaticaly. The problem is about slicing the records.
Lets say i have five records and my grid shows 3 of them per page; "1", "2","3" for the first page and "4","5" for the second.
After i reverse it; "5","4","3","2","1"
Before slicing the records i see "5","4","3","2","1" on the grid's first(/w breakpoint) page. after sliced it becomes "3","2","1" for the first page and "5","4" for the second. What i want is "5","4","3" for the first and "2","1" for the second.

Comment: you mean that they are unsorted? Then add a sorter on the store like so.. `sorters : [{property : 'name', direction : 'ASC'}]`

Comment: They are sorted. But there is a problem with paging. "5","4" should be in the first page but they are still in the second. It looks like only the page is sorted, not the whole store.. But i know that the whole the store is sorted. This is the part that i don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change store listener like this,

```
listeners: {
                  load : function (store, records, success, operation, options) {
                    if(records != null && records.length > 0){
                        function compare(a,b) {
                          if (a.get(sortIndex) < b.get(sortIndex))
                             return -1;
                          if (a.get(sortIndex) > b.get(sortIndex))
                            return 1;
                          return 0;
                        }
                        records.sort(compare);
                        if(sortDirection == "DESC"){
                            records.reverse();
                        }
                        store.loadData(records.slice(records[0].get('start'),records[0].get('start')+4));
                    }
                  } 
                }
```

and sortchange listener like this,

```
 sortIndex = column.dataIndex;
 sortDirection = direction;
```

it works!